# STATIC_URL Not Working on Django 1.5

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I cannot load .css and .js files. This is what I get on the server as output:

[29/Oct/2013 11:33:26] "GET /static/srt/css/django-admin-widgets.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1700

[29/Oct/2013 11:33:26] "GET /static/srt/js/django-admin.multiselect.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1706

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'srt_project.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^srt_project/', include('srt_project.foo.urls')),

# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
# url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),

url(r'^srt/', include('srt.urls', app_name='srt')),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

site_base.html

```
{% load static from staticfiles%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Status Reporting Tool</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'srt/css/django-admin-widgets.css' %}" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'srt/js/django-admin.multiselect.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery.each($("select[multiple]"), function () {  
        // "Locations" can be any label you want  
        SelectFilter.init(this.id, "Viewers", 0, "/static/srt/");  
        });  
    </script>
```

Directory Structure:

```
.---srt_project
|   manage.py
|                   
+---srt
|   |   admin.py
|   |   forms.py
|   |   models.py
|   |   tables.py
|   |   tests.py
|   |   urls.py
|   |   views.py
|   |   __init__.py
|               
\---srt_project
    |   settings.py
    |   srt_project.sqlite
    |   urls.py
    |   wsgi.py
    |   __init__.py
    |   
    \---static
        \---srt
            +---css
            |       django-admin-widgets.css
            |       
            \---js
                    django-admin.multiselect.js
```

Comment: Your web-server should handle static files. You may put an alias in your htacess or server conf to serve your static files.

Comment: @Jingo I don't think that's the issue. I'm running it on a development server with DEBUG=True. From docs:
"In addition to these configuration steps, you’ll also need to actually serve the static files.

During development, this will be done automatically if you use runserver and DEBUG is set to True (see django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()).
This method is grossly inefficient and probably insecure, so it is unsuitable for production."

Comment: That is my point, development server automatically serves the files for you if you are using runserver command (which is what I'm doing). So I'm not exactly sure what you are implying, could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I'm getting a 304 on the .js and .css files, so looks like I have fixed it. I just had to change my folder name from 'static' to 'staticfiles', in my inner srt_project directory. Though it doesn't makes any sense to me as to how this is possible, if 'static' is now 'staticfiles':

```
[29/Oct/2013 12:50:48] "GET /static/srt/css/django-admin-widgets.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[29/Oct/2013 12:50:48] "GET /static/srt/js/django-admin.multiselect.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

Could someone please explain it?

Comment: Because you ran `collectstatic`, which does exactly that: copies everything to staticfiles. However, you're right to say you shouldn't have needed to in development.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of things to check:

- Did you include `django.contrib.staticfiles` in `INSTALLED_APPS`?
- Did you include `srt` in `INSTALLED_APPS`?
- Is `DEBUG = True` or `False`? If it's `False` then `staticfiles_urlpatterns` won't work.
- (in deployment) Did you run `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: Thanks Simeon. django.contrib.staticfiles and srt included in INSTALLED_APPS. DEBUG = True. Didn't deploy yet, running as development on localhost. Had to make an empty folder staticfiles in the inner srt_project folder to run collectstatic. Not sure what that did though, copied bunch of files.. I don' think that would make any difference during development, but not sure.